Does chronic THC consumption affect sweating or thermoregulation?
I am wondering how regular long term consumption of THC affects sweating and thermoregulation.
I can't seem to find any papers studying the connection between CB1 activity and sweating / thermoregulation but I often read from people with excessive sweating who are also regular long term (>10 years) cannabis users. I also know 4 people who consume cannabis for >15 years and 3 of 4 mention having developed higher than usual amount of sweating in the past years.
THC withdrawal also causes sweating, so I'm wondering by which mechanism this works and why there seem to be individuals developing excessive sweating after long term (>10years) use of cannabis.
I know that ACh is a ligand involved in the regulation of sweating through the sympathetic nervous system so I suppose any indirect effect on thermoregulation and sweating should happen because of indirect changes to ACh release/production/transport or are there other neurotransmitters involved in regulating body temperature and sweating?
Is the relative balance of different neurotransmitters relevant? or do only absolute levels of ACh play a role? Can CB1 projections affect signalling or transport of ligands or otherwise interfere with the functioning of the sympathetic system?
I believe muscarinic receptors are G-Protein coupled so maybe this or secondary messenger functions can be disturbed by chronic CB1 activity.
